# Getting select options from computed properties with Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, reactive

I am trying to get a select from to work with Vue using a computed property.

Here's a fiddle I'm working with: https://jsfiddle.net/2m18ab1v/13/

Here's what my view-model looks like:

```
var vm = new Vue({
        el: "#app-container",
        data: {
            offer: {
                unit: '',
                tags: '',
            },
            protocol: protocol
        },             
        computed: {
            getUnits: function(){
                var unitsList = [];
                var tagList = this.offer.tags.split(",");
                console.log(tagList);
                for (var i=0; i<tagList.length; i++){
                    unitsList += this.protocol[tagList[i]]["units"];
                }
                console.log(unitsList);
                return unitsList;
            }
        }

    });
```

And the 'protocol' object referenced in the data:

```
var protocol = {"wireless":
                {
                 "units": {"bandwidth": "bit/s", "distance": "kilometers"},
                 "children": [],
                }
```

I would like to have as my `<select>` choices "bit/s" and "kilometers".  I've been trying something like this in my template:

```
           <div id="app-container">
                  <select v-model="offer.unit">
                    <option  v-for="item in getUnits" v-bind:value="value">
                      {{ item }}

                    </option>
                  </select>
              </div>
```

`console.log(unitsList)` returns `Object { bandwidth: Getter, distance: Getter, 1 more… }`

So apparently, what I am trying to get is an object of some sort.  I'm somewhat new to Vue and I'm trying to make sense of how the "Getter" works. Is there a straightforward way to get its value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are trying to collect the units, using `+=` in js won't get you the desired result. In this [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sacfn1nb/), I used `concat` instead, to concat the `units` under `wireless` with others. (assuming you have other protocol categories on the same data tree level as `wireless`) Depending on your actual need, you may need `push`. Take a look at their docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push